# Transition Probability greater than 1? (In Perturbation)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory

This topic already is widely discussed in this pot, but I can't find a direct answer boiling down to my question.

**Question**

Considering a constant perturbation $V$ on a system in initial state $|\varphi_i>$

The transition probability $P$ for $|\varphi_i> \:\to\: |\varphi_f>$ (The system switching into a final State due to $V$) should be:$\\[12pt]$

$$P_{i\to f} = \dfrac{4\,|V_{fi}|^2}{\hbar^2}\,\Bigg|\sin\left(\dfrac{{(\omega_{fi}\cdot t})/{2}}{\omega_{fi}}\right)\Bigg|^{2}\quad \text{where} \quad V_{fi}\: =\: <\varphi_f|V|\varphi_i>\quad \text{and} \quad \omega_{fi} =\dfrac{E_f-E_i}{\hbar}\\[12pt]$$

Now for a really long perturbation thus $t\to\infty$ this should rewrite to: $\\[12pt]$

$$P_{i\to f} = t\cdot\dfrac{2\pi}{\hbar}\,|V_{fi}|^2\,\delta(E_f-E_i)\\[12pt]$$

I fairly get the interpretation: If you really wait a large amount of time, the Probability only will be $\neq0$ if $E_f = E_i$.

This is to say $|\varphi_f>$ only will adapt the energy of $|\varphi_i>$. $\left(\text{Even in accordance with uncertainty:} \Delta t\,\Delta E \geq \dfrac{\hbar}{2}\right)$

**But the gist I don't grasp:** How to even explain $P \to \infty$ for $E_f = E_i$ ?

I always read the Probability is less than 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expression is a result valid to first order in the perturbation.  For long times restricting to first order is a poor approximation and one should include higher order terms.  A sign that keeping only the first order term is poor is precisely that the transition probability becomes unphysically greater than 1.

This is similar to writing $\sin(\omega t)\approx \omega t$.  This is only valid for small values of $\omega t$.  It makes no sense to use this approximation when $\omega t$ is not small.  Indeed:
$$
\sin(\omega t)\approx \omega t -\frac{1}{6}(\omega t)^3 +\ldots
$$
clearly showing that you can keep the first term only when $\frac{1}{6}(\omega t)^3\ll 1$.  If you keep only the first order correction then for sufficiently large $t$ you would get $\omega t>1$, something impossible for the sine function.